# How advisable is it to install a 36" gas cooktop in a 30" cabinet plus adjoining?

Tags: kitchens, gas, cabinets, cooktops

House we are working on has a 30" electric cooktop.   I already have the gas set up to convert to a gas cooktop but designer suggested 36".   There is an 8" cabinet (draw/skinny cabinet) next to it.   I could turn drawer into faux door pretty easy but I have never cut out the tops of the edges like this and it would be 3-4" on the 30" and the 8" side.   Stick to 30"?

Comment: How handy do you find the 8 inch cabinet, a waste of space, it's there so use it, or can't do without it?

Comment: Designers - feh. 6" of countertop (and a functional drawer) is much more useful than taking up 6" more with cooktop. The extra space on the cooktop buys you exactly nothing *actually useful* most of the time. But it costs more.

Comment: Seems to me that unless you cut into the cabinets on either side of the cooktop, it will not be centered over the 30" cabinet it is meant to be above. That is not going to look right. While it would be nice to have the extra space for the cooktop, I do not see this as a viable option.

Comment: As @Kyle syas are you also going to extend the hood and the cabinets over it?  The just seems like a bodge unless you're also replacing cabinets ro you are a serious cook who often uses up all cookspace in a 30" cooktop.  While we're at it, gas cooktops are actively bad for you.  Look it up.  Go induction or stay where you are.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any trouble notching the sides of the cabinets to allow the cooktop to span the cabinets. Leave enough 'side' at the front so the face of the cabinets don't wobble.

At my old job in a cabinet shop, we'd notch cabinet sides for sinks that the designer just had to have but were too wide for the sink.

FWIW once the cabinet sides are cut it's hard to uncut them when a later owner wants to go back to 30". And you don't have to follow your designer's recommendation, too. But if you're ready to commit, then you should be fine notching the cabinet sides.